# Retrieving POST request from outer application to Laravel: 419 unknown status

Tags: php, laravel, httpclient

I am trying to send POST request from [advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=ja) for Chrome to Laravel App:

[image]

I understand that Laravel has the protection from request like it, but what I need, for example, to update the database from some native application, like UWP? (Of course, I use **advanced REST client** for testing for now).

I tried [Laravel JSON API](http://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). With below code, I retrieve error **419 unknown status** (also, `dump('done')` has not been reached:

```
Route::post('api/update', function(){
  dump('done');
  $guzzleClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.loc/api/update/']);
  $client = json_api('v1')->client($guzzleClient);
});
```

What I missed? Please let me know WHERE I need to add code from your solution (controller, **web.php** etc.).

Comment: why are you using web.php for api. In routes there is api.php for your api

Comment: @Mahesh Bhattarai , because I don't know why I should not.

Comment: prefix with api is configured for api.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write in your api.php

```
Route::get('/update',function(){
    return response()->json("test");
});
```

and check with same url in rest client
http://example.loc/api/update/
and see result

Comment: Thank your for the answer! Everything works correctly.